# Not able to unzip a password protected zip file

Tags: unzip, password-protection

I am trying to unzip a password-protected zip folder in Windows 11 OS. I have the password, however when I clicked 'Extract Al...' and confirmed the extract location, it didn't ask me for the password; instead, it showed the following error:
[image]
and this happened for every single file in the zipped folder.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try 7-zip. Or check the file if its corrupt via checksum, if possible.